# How to draw cover on each tile in 'memory' in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am a beginner in pygame and I am not a English native speaker.

My assignment is coding a game called 'Memory'. This game contains 8 pairs pictures and an cover exists on each pictures. This week, our assignment is draw covers and if you click an cover, this cover will disappear. However, although I draw pictures successfully. I still cannot draw covers properly. Actually, I don't know the approaches that to draw an cover and to click an cover and make it disappear. I searched a lot however, maybe because I am not a native speaker, I cannot really understand how it works. Therefore, I hope someone could help me here. I will provide my code and pictures below. Thanks everyone!

```
# This is version 1 for 'Memory'.
# This version contains complete tile grid, but not the score. 
# All 8 pairs of two tiles should be exposed when the game starts. 
# Each time the game is played, the tiles must be in random locations in the grid. 
# Player actions must be ignored.

import pygame, sys, time, random 
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

# User-defined Class

class Tile:
    bgColor=pygame.Color('black')
    BorderWidth= 3



    def __init__(self, x, y, image, surface):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.surface = surface
        self.image= image

    def DrawTile(self):

        self.surface.blit( self.image , (self.x, self.y))



class Memory:

    boardWidthSize=4
    boardHeightSize=4 
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.board = []
        self.cover = []
        self.board2= []
    def createImages(self):
        #load images from file  
        self.cover=[]
        self.imageNames = ['image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image7.bmp','image8.bmp','image1.bmp','image2.bmp','image3.bmp','image4.bmp','image5.bmp','image6.bmp','image7.bmp','image8.bmp']
        self.images=[]
        for name in self.imageNames :

            pic = pygame.image.load(name)
            self.images.append(pic) 
            random.shuffle(self.images)
        self.cover.append(pygame.image.load('image0.bmp'))

    def createTile(self):

        board =[]
        board2=[]
        #loop through the loaded images and create tile objects
        for rowIndex in range(0,Memory.boardWidthSize):
            row = []
            row2=[]
            for columnIndex in range(0,Memory.boardHeightSize):
                width = 100
                x = columnIndex*width
                height = 100
                y = rowIndex*height
                tile = Tile(x, y, self.images[rowIndex*4+columnIndex], self.surface)
                cover= Tile(x, y, self.cover, self.surface)
                row.append(tile)
                row2.append(cover)
            self.board.append(row)
            self.board2.append(row2)



    def GetScore(self):
        position=(400,0)
        FontSize=50
        FontColor=pygame.Color('White')
        String='Score : '
        font=pygame.font.SysFont(None, FontSize, True)
        surface1=font.render(str(pygame.time.get_ticks()/1000), True, FontColor,0)
        self.surface.blit(surface1,position)    



    def draw(self):
        for row in self.board:
            for tile in row:
                tile.DrawTile()


    def update(self):
        if False:
            return True
        else:
            self.createTile()
            return False



def main():
    surfaceSize = (500, 400) 
    windowTitle = 'Memory'
    # No frame delay since no moving objects
    gameOver = False
    # Create the window
    surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
    pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)
    memory = Memory(surface)
    memory.createImages()
    memory.createTile()

    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        memory.draw()
        memory.GetScore()
        gameOver = memory.update()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

I upload these pictures in my Google Drive:

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx-bEVazt-TWUnRSZlJVRmhfQm8&usp=sharing

Comment: I don't have permission to view the google drive document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example with drawing cover and handle click (and hide card after 2000ms)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pygame

class Tile:

    def __init__(self, x, y, image, cover):
        self.image = image
        self.cover = cover
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60)
        self.covered = True
        self.time_to_cover = None

    def draw(self, screen):
        # draw cover or image
        if self.covered:
            screen.blit(self.cover, self.rect)
        else:
            screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        # hide card (after 2000ms)
        if not self.covered and pygame.time.get_ticks() >= self.time_to_cover:
            self.covered = True

    def handle_event(self, event):
        # check left button click
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            # check position 
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                self.covered = not self.covered
                if not self.covered:
                    # if uncovered then set +2000ms to cover
                    self.time_to_cover = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 2000

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

# init

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((320,320))

# create images

img = pygame.surface.Surface((60, 60))
img.fill((255,0,0))

cov = pygame.surface.Surface((60, 60))
cov.fill((0,255,0))

# create tiles

tiles = []
for y in range(5):
    for x in range(5):
        tiles.append( Tile(x*65, y*65, img, cov) )

# mainloop

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

while running:

    # events

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        for x in tiles:
            x.handle_event(event)

    # updates

    for x in tiles:
        x.update()

    # draws

    for x in tiles:
        x.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    # clock

    clock.tick(25)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks a million! I success by your guide!