# How to use time.sleep in pygame?

Tags: python, time, pygame

So i am trying to display an image, wait 1 second and then display another image. I'm making a matching game, so in my code I'm trying to say that if two images don't match, I want to change the image to just a preset generic one. So my code for that would look something like this:

```
if True:
    self.content = self.image
    time.sleep(1)
    self.content = Tile.cover
```

`self.content` is a variable for what is being displayed, `self.image` is the image that displays, and then `Tile.cover` is the generic image that covers the other one. Yet whenever I do this the code skips the first line, and just sets the image to `Tile.cover`, why?

Comment: Perhaps you have to redraw before `time.sleep(1)`?

Comment: What is the type of self? Can you give us a bit more details/code?
As said in the prévious comment, it's probably linked to the fact you have to update the display. You probably have something like "pygame.display.update()" somewhere. You could use the debugger to locate precisely when (what line) the Tile.cover is printed

Comment: `sleep()` stops all functions in program so nobody use it. Solution need a lot more modifications.

Comment: see example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/33935509/1832058

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Pygame, you have to use [`pygame.time.wait()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.wait) instead of python's `time.sleep()`.

It takes time in *milliseconds*:

```
pygame.time.wait(1000)
```

The reason for not using `time.sleep` is because it will block pygame's event loop and so pygame will not be able to process other events.

Comment: Alos `pygame.time.wait()` blocks the application/event loop. `wait` and `sleep` cannot be used to control timing in a typical Pygame application.