# class method not running inside the code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am coding a simple game and I am having the next trouble:

```
if pidgeon.rect.y > 360:

    pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    pidgeon.electrocute()
    electrocute.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    showGameOverScreen(score, total_score)
```

The method that is not working is:

```
pidgeon.electrocute()
```

Which should do the next:

```
def electrocute(self):
    self.image=pygame.image.load(r"electrocuted_pidgeon.png").convert() 
    self.image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
```

But instead of changing the pidgeon image, while playing the electrocute sound. It just waits the 2 seconds, while playing the electrocute sound and then it goes to the gameover screen. Why is it not changing the image?

I've tried in other parts of the code (e.g. when pressing bar space it should change, and it does), so the image can change.

I am using pygame in python 2.7, just in case.

Comment: I'm not familiar with pygame (at all), but I think calling `time.sleep` is probably a bad idea. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932722/how-to-use-time-sleep-in-pygame) for example.

Comment: Thank you, I will search for an alternative.

Comment: define you method before the `if` statement and try, and also try with small out put in the method like `print("something")`

Comment: The method is defined before, inside the Pidgeon class.

Comment: you have to create an instance of the class, before you call the methods inside the class.I will add small example

Answer (score 0):

try to call it like this. this is a small example based on user input value.

```
class fly:
    def mymethod(self):
        print("canada")

def testmethod():
    print("this should be greater")

for i in range(0,3):
    userInput = int(input("Enter any number :"))

    if(userInput > 5):
        print("greater")

    else:
        testmethod()
        s = fly()
        s.mymethod()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but till now, nothing worked, python still running the sleep(pygame.delay, pygame.wait) before changing the image.