# Adding a delay in "virus"

Tags: python

We're doing a *"virus"* now and I was told to make a delay in my code. Help me, please. **Here's the code**:

```
import pygame         
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
import time               
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("ЗАРАЖЕНИЕ АЧЕ)")

Tk().wm_withdraw()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Lucida Console", 35)
label2 = font.render("DELETING ALL PASSWORDS. . . . .", 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))

a = 0

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
            pygame.display.set_caption("ЗАРАЖЕНИЕ АЧЕ)")
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", " Вы попытались закрыть окно! Начинаю удаление файлов")
    warning = f"Процент удаления: {a}"
    label3 = font.render(warning, 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))
    a = a + 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if a >= 100:
        break

    screen.blit(label2, (50, 50))
    screen.blit(label3, (50, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

My **question** is, I don't know which command to use to delay and where to put it.

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: Please give textual information and code as text, not as link to picture of text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7733418 That is part of providing a helpful [mre].

Comment: what should be delayed?

Comment: @Sadap warning = f"Процент удаления: {a}"
    label3 = font.render(warning, 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))
    a = a + 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if a >= 100:
        break

Comment: @Andrew then place `time.sleep(2)` before that line. `2` is the number of seconds to wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pygame, you don't use `time.sleep`, you need to replace your `time.sleep` code with [pygame.time.wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932722/how-to-use-time-sleep-in-pygame), which is written in milliseconds, so your updated code would look like so:

```
import pygame         
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox 
import time               
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption("ЗАРАЖЕНИЕ АЧЕ)")

Tk().wm_withdraw()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Lucida Console", 35)
label2 = font.render("DELETING ALL PASSWORDS. . . . .", 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))

a = 0

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.time.wait(500)
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 300))
            pygame.display.set_caption("ЗАРАЖЕНИЕ АЧЕ)")
            messagebox.showerror("ERROR!", " Вы попытались закрыть окно! Начинаю удаление файлов")
    warning = f"Процент удаления: {a}"
    label3 = font.render(warning, 1, (12, 140, 0, 1))
    a = a + 1
    pygame.time.wait(100)
    if a >= 100:
        break

    screen.blit(label2, (50, 50))
    screen.blit(label3, (50, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Also with your code I replaced `pygame.quit()` with `pygame.display.quit()` so the code will continue after the so called "error".

Comment: Thank you very much!